# Issue when sliding element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to develop the following carousel.

http://jsfiddle.net/2kLanjwn/2/

It should work in this way.

- Clicking the button DOWN, carousel scrolls and resize always div in the center.

I am not able to apply the same logic on the reverse, so when I click button UP I need to contract the central div, and sliding up.

I kindly you what I am doing wrong and if you would be able to fix it on jsfiddle.
Also I would like to know if there is any better way to achieve that same effect or a component that can be reused.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Scroll text box example</title>
        <style>
            #btn-up, #btn-down {
                position: absolute;
                top: 600px;
            }

            #btn-up {
                left: 0px;
            }

            #btn-down {
                left: 50px;
            }

            #btn-up, #btn-down {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: yellow;
                outline: 1px solid black;
            }

            #content-scroll-container {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0px;
                width: 500px;
                height: 250px; /* MASK HEIGHT real mask would be 200*/
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #content-scroll-inner {
                position: absolute;
            }

            .cnt {
                height: 100px;
                width: 500px;
                background-color: red;
            }

                .cnt:nth-child(even) {
                    height: 100px;
                    background-color: pink;
                }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scroller = {
                config: {
                    curPos: 0,              // position
                    canExpand: false,
                    el: 'content-scroll-container',     // visible area (container)
                    elInner: 'content-scroll-inner',    // inner content
                    cntPosY: null,          // content top-left corner (0 position)
                    cntHeight: null,        // content lenght
                    maskHeight: null,       // visible area (rest is masked out)
                    canMoveUp: null,        // true jquery can slide up content
                    canMoveDown: null,      // true jquery can slide down content
                    increment: 100,         // slide of x pixel when user perfom an action
                    incrementOf: 0,         // how much we have slided the contnt
                    animationSpeed: 500,    // jquery animation speed, use 0 for no animation
                    isAnimationOn: false,   // true when jquery is performing animation
                },
                data: '<div id="cnt-0" class="cnt">0</div><div id="cnt-1" class="cnt">1</div><div id="cnt-2" class="cnt">2</div><div id="cnt-3" class="cnt">3</div><div id="cnt-4" class="cnt">4</div><div id="cnt-5" class="cnt">5 empty</div>',
                getCntPosition: function () {
                    // get y position of content
                    var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.elInner);
                    this.config.cntPosY = elm.offsetTop;
                },
                getCntSize: function () {
                    // get height for content
                    var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.elInner);
                    this.config.cntHeight = elm.clientHeight;
                },
                getMaskSize: function () {
                    // get height visible area
                    var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.el);
                    this.config.maskHeight = elm.clientHeight;
                },
                updateData: function () {
                    // refresh state
                    this.getMaskSize();
                    this.getCntPosition();
                    this.getCntSize();
                    this.canMoveUpCheck();
                    this.canMoveDownCheck();
                    //console.clear();
                    console.log(this.config);
                },
                canMoveUpCheck: function () {
                    // set flags allowing sliding up (in case we have enought content to show)
                    var lastScreenY = (this.config.cntHeight - this.config.maskHeight); // last screen visible
                    if ((this.config.incrementOf * -1) < lastScreenY)
                        this.config.canMoveUp = true;
                    else
                        this.config.canMoveUp = false;
                },
                canMoveDownCheck: function () {
                    // set flags allowing sliding down (in case we have enought content to show)
                    if (this.config.cntPosY >= 0)
                        this.config.canMoveDown = false; // cannot move more up if content is on start position (0 position)
                    else
                        this.config.canMoveDown = true;
                },
                goUp: function () {
                    // user want to read previose content
                    //this.updateData();
                    if (this.config.canMoveDown == true && this.config.isAnimationOn == false) {
                        this.moveCnt('down'); // content go down
                    }
                },
                goDown: function () { //**************************
                    // user want to read next content
                    //this.updateData();
                    if (this.config.canMoveUp == true && this.config.isAnimationOn == false) {
                        // check newPos
                        var newPos = this.config.curPos + 1;
                        if (newPos > 0) { // special case
                            if (this.config.canExpand == true)
                                this.config.increment = 150;
                            this.config.canExpand = true;
                            this.moveCnt('up');
                        }



                    }
                },
                moveCnt: function (direction) {
                    // do the actual animation
                    var moveOf;
                    this.isAnimationOn = true;
                    if (direction == 'up') {
                        this.config.curPos++;
                        if (this.config.cntPosY == 0) { // special case for first item
                            moveOf = '-=' + (this.config.increment / 2);
                        }
                        else {
                            moveOf = '-=' + this.config.increment;
                        }
                        var target = '#' + this.config.elInner + ':not(:animated)';
                        $(target).animate({ 'top': moveOf }, this.animationSpeed, this.cbEndAnimation.bind(this, direction));
                    } else if (direction == 'down') {
                        this.config.curPos++;
                        var distanceToFp = (this.config.increment / 2); // height to reach first page (special page)
                        var distanceToFp = 50;
                        if (this.config.cntPosY == (distanceToFp * -1)) {
                            moveOf = '+=' + distanceToFp;
                            // i need to contract only the firs tone
                            $('cnt-1').css({ height: '100px' }, 500, this.cbEndAnimationExpand.bind(this));
                        } else {
                            moveOf = '+=' + this.config.increment;
                        }
                        var target = '#' + this.config.elInner + ':not(:animated)';
                        $(target).animate({ 'top': moveOf }, this.animationSpeed, this.cbEndAnimation.bind(this));

                    }
                    //var target = '#' + this.config.elInner + ':not(:animated)';
                    //$(target).animate({ 'top': moveOf }, this.animationSpeed, this.cbEndAnimation.bind(this, direction));
                },
                cbEndAnimation: function (direction) {
                    // runs when animation end
                    this.config.isAnimationOn = false;
                    if (direction == 'up') {
                        this.config.incrementOf -= this.config.increment;
                        if (this.config.canExpand == true) {    // expand
                            this.logicExpand();
                        } else {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    }
                    else if (direction == 'down') {
                        this.config.incrementOf += this.config.increment;

                    }
                    this.updateData(); // refresh state has element has just moved
                    this.logicShowHideArrows();
                },
                logicExpand: function () {
                    // take contenf and expand it
                    var elm = document.getElementById('cnt-' + this.config.curPos);
                    $(elm).animate({ height: '150px' }, 500, this.cbEndAnimationExpand.bind(this));
                },
                cbEndAnimationExpand: function () {
                    console.log('end anim expand');
                },
                logicContract: function () {
                    var elm = document.getElementById('cnt-' + this.config.curPos);
                    $(elm).animate({ height: '-=50px' }, 500, this.cbEndAnimationContract.bind(this));
                },
                logicShowHideArrows: function () {
                    // reset first
                    this.hideArrow('btn-up');
                    this.hideArrow('btn-down');
                    if (this.config.canMoveUp == true)
                        this.showArrow('btn-down');
                    if (this.config.canMoveDown == true)
                        this.showArrow('btn-up');
                },
                cbEndAnimationContract: function () {
                    this.config.isAnimationOn = false;
                    this.moveCnt('down'); // content go down
                },
                showArrow: function (elmName) {
                    var elm = document.getElementById(elmName);
                    elm.style.display = '';
                },
                hideArrow: function (elmName) {
                    var elm = document.getElementById(elmName);
                    elm.style.display = 'none';
                },
                setEventHandler: function () {
                    // envet handlers for arrows
                    var btnUp = document.getElementById('btn-up');
                    btnUp.addEventListener('click', this.goUp.bind(this), false);
                    var btnDown = document.getElementById('btn-down');
                    btnDown.addEventListener('click', this.goDown.bind(this), false);
                },
                renderData: function () {
                    // render data content to slide
                    var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.elInner);
                    elm.innerHTML = this.data;
                },
                start: function () {
                    this.renderData();
                    this.updateData();
                    this.setEventHandler();
                    this.logicShowHideArrows(); // at start set arrows visibility
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="scroller.start();">
        <div id="content-scroll-container">
            <div id="content-scroll-inner">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="btn-up">UP</div>
        <div id="btn-down">DOWN</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find what in your code is wrong, but I made some changes to it, and it worked. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Scroll text box example</title>
    <style>
        #btn-up, #btn-down {
            position: absolute;
            top: 400px;
        }

        #btn-up {
            left: 0px;
        }

        #btn-down {
            left: 50px;
        }

        #btn-up, #btn-down {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: yellow;
            outline: 1px solid black;
        }

        #content-scroll-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0px;
            width: 500px;
            height: 250px; /* MASK HEIGHT real mask would be 200*/
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #content-scroll-inner {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .cnt {
            height: 100px;
            width: 500px;
            background-color: red;
        }

            .cnt:nth-child(even) {
                height: 100px;
                background-color: pink;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scroller = {
            config: {
                curPos: 0,              // position
                el: 'content-scroll-container',     // visible area (container)
                elInner: 'content-scroll-inner',    // inner content
                cntPosY: null,          // content top-left corner (0 position)
                cntHeight: null,        // content lenght
                maskHeight: null,       // visible area (rest is masked out)
                animationSpeed: 500,    // jquery animation speed, use 0 for no animation
                isAnimationOn: false,   // true when jquery is performing animation
            },
            data: '<div id="cnt-0" class="cnt">0</div><div id="cnt-1" class="cnt">1</div><div id="cnt-2" class="cnt">2</div><div id="cnt-3" class="cnt">3</div><div id="cnt-4" class="cnt">4</div><div id="cnt-5" class="cnt">5 empty</div>',
            getCntPosition: function () {
                // get y position of content
                var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.elInner);
                this.config.cntPosY = elm.offsetTop;
            },
            getCntSize: function () {
                // get height for content
                var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.elInner);
                this.config.cntHeight = elm.clientHeight;
            },
            getMaskSize: function () {
                // get height visible area
                var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.el);
                this.config.maskHeight = elm.clientHeight;
            },
            updateData: function () {
                // refresh state
                this.getMaskSize();
                this.getCntPosition();
                this.getCntSize();
                //console.clear();
                console.log(this.config);
            },
            logicShowHideArrows: function () {
                if(this.config.curPos<1) {
                    $('#btn-up').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#btn-up').show();
                }
                if(this.config.curPos>=4) {
                    $('#btn-down').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#btn-down').show();
                }
            },
            goUp: function () {

                if(this.config.curPos<4 && scroller.config.isAnimationOn ==false) {
                    scroller.config.isAnimationOn = true;
                    scroller.config.curPos++;
                    if(scroller.config.curPos==1) {
                        $('#content-scroll-inner').animate({'top':'-=50px'},500,function(){
                            $('#cnt-'+scroller.config.curPos).animate({'height':'+=50px'},500);
                            scroller.logicShowHideArrows();
                            scroller.config.isAnimationOn = false;
                        });
                        this.config.incrementOf-=50;
                        $('#btn-up').show();
                    }
                    else {
                         $('#content-scroll-inner').animate({'top':'-=150px'},500,function(){
                            $('#cnt-'+scroller.config.curPos).animate({'height':'+=50px'},500);
                            scroller.logicShowHideArrows();
                            scroller.config.isAnimationOn = false;
                        });
                            this.config.incrementOf-=150;
                    }
                    this.updateData();
                } 

            },
            goDown: function () { //**************************
                // user want to read next content
                //this.updateData();
                if(this.config.curPos>0 && scroller.config.isAnimationOn ==false) {
                    scroller.config.isAnimationOn = true;
                    if(this.config.curPos==1) {
                        $('#cnt-'+scroller.config.curPos).animate({'height':'-=50px'},500,function(){
                           $('#content-scroll-inner').animate({'top':'+=50px'},500);
                           scroller.logicShowHideArrows();
                           scroller.config.isAnimationOn = false;
                        });
                        scroller.config.curPos--;
                        this.config.incrementOf+=150;
                        this.updateData();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#cnt-'+scroller.config.curPos).animate({'height':'-=50px'},500,function(){
                           $('#content-scroll-inner').animate({'top':'+=150px'},500);
                           scroller.logicShowHideArrows();
                           scroller.config.isAnimationOn = false;
                        });
                        scroller.config.curPos--;
                        this.config.incrementOf+=150;
                        this.updateData();
                    }
                }
            },

            setEventHandler: function () {
                $('#btn-up').click(function() {
                    scroller.goDown();
                });
                $('#btn-down').click(function() {
                    scroller.goUp();
                });
            },
            renderData: function () {
                // render data content to slide
                var elm = document.getElementById(this.config.elInner);
                elm.innerHTML = this.data;
            },
            start: function () {
                this.renderData();
                this.updateData();
                this.setEventHandler();
                this.logicShowHideArrows();
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="scroller.start();">
    <div id="content-scroll-container">
        <div id="content-scroll-inner">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="btn-up">UP</div>
    <div id="btn-down">DOWN</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works great! Many many thanks for your help, I would up-vote your answer 100 times but I can only one :-)

Comment: do you have any idea how to solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341419/how-to-position-a-div-with-absolute-inside-a-div-with-relative-position ? Once again thanks for your help on this question!